# Hibernate dialect Issues with update to Oracle 12.2 C database when using Grails

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We are running Grails 2.3.11 on JRE 1.8_211.  We have Hibernate version - 3.6.10.6. 
When we were working with Oracle 11, it was working fine but when I upgrade to 12.2C, we get following error:-

> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [Oracle]!

On reverting back to Oracle 11, the issue gets resolved.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for migrating my application to Oracle 12.2C.

Answer (score 0):

We had not specified the hibernate dialect in one of the datasources in datasource.groovy.

It seems that in oracle 12C, it is mandatory to specify the dialect for each data source even though it is not mandatory for Oracle 11g.

Hence, during migrating from Oracle 11g to Oracle 12C, please add verifying that dialects are explicitly specified in your checklist.

Hope this helps others.